# Keeping and setting object child properties default values without knowing the prop names

Tags: javascript, object, redux, vuex

```
user = {
  firstName: 'Nick',
  age: 35
  location: {
    country: 'USA',
    city: 'NYC',
  },
}
```

I am often running in this scenario:

I have a mutation/reducer which needs to set several props at their default values. I would like to not have to explicitly unset / reset them one by one. (for example: a user logout: `user.firstName = ''`, etc).

What's the most efficient, safe and performant way to remove each of those values (and set to null or empty string) without knowing the structure of the object? Any lodash or other libraries with a method for that use?

I am basically thinking of a recursive solution using `for...in`

```
for (prop in user) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

or `Object.keys`, or keeping a default object that can replace the previous one.

Desired result

```
user = {
  firstName: '',
  age: null,
  location: {
    country: '',
    city: '',
  },
}
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would use `Object.keys` because `for..in` iterates through the enumerable properties in the prototype chain as well, i don't think you would want that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function to set all the values to null or empty string. If the value is an object, pass it back into the function.

```js
let user = {
  firstName: 'Nick',
  age: 35,
  location: {
    country: 'USA',
    city: 'NYC',
  },
}

function nullify(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      return nullify(obj[key]);
    }
    obj[key] = (typeof obj[key] === 'string') ? '' : null;
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(nullify(user));
```

Comment: I clarified my question a bit more as I think what I need is a default object

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the wrong way. My question was part a Vuex implementation - Vuex provides an API with a method to reset state programmatically. 
A simple `Object.assign(state, defaultState);` can do the trick.